# Python: Match two elements in a tuple, return the 3rd

Tags: python, tuples, string-comparison

I have a set of input conditions that I need to compare and produce a 3rd value based on the two inputs. a list of 3 element tuples seems like a reasonable choice for this. Where I could use some help is in building an compact method for processing it. I've laid out the structure I was thinking of using as follows:

input1 (string) compares to first element, input2 (string) compares to second element, if they match, return 3rd element

```
('1','a', string1)
('1','b', string2)
('1','c', string3)
('1','d', string3)
('2','a', invalid)
('2','b', invalid)
('2','c', string3)
('2','d', string3)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a dict, dicts can have tuple as keys and store the third item as it's value.

Using a dict will provide an `O(1)` lookup for any pair of `(input1,input2)`.

```
dic = {('1','a'): string1, ('1','b'):string2, ('1','c'): string3....}

if (input1,input2) in dic:
   return dic[input1,input2]
else:
   #do something else
```

Using a list of tuples in this case will be an `O(N)` approach, as for every `input1`,`input2` you've to loop through the whole list of tuples(in worst case).

Comment: Ahh! just full of helpful info :) Thanks Again Ashwini!

Answer (score 2):

Could use a dict with a 2-tuple as key, and its value as your string/whatever and then you can keep the look to only include valid values, and have a default value of invalid if you wished... (by using `dict.get`)

So if you have a list of `refs`, you can then convert them into a `dict` and perform lookups as such:

```
refs = [
    ('1','a', 'string1'),
    ('1','b', 'string2'),
    ('1','c', 'string3'),
    ('1','d', 'string3'),
    ('2','a', 'invalid'),
    ('2','b', 'invalid'),
    ('2','c', 'string3'),
    ('2','d', 'string3')
]

lookup = {ref[:2]:ref[2] for ref in refs}

print lookup['1', 'd']
#string3
print lookup.get(('I do not', 'exist'), 'uh oh, in trouble now!')
# uh oh, in trouble now!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkIfSame(t):
    if t[0] == t[1]:
        return t[2]
```

I'm pretty sure this should work for you.